# Fetch Keep Alive is not working as expected

Tags: angularjs, fetch-api, onbeforeunload, onunload

I am working on AngularJS 1.6 version.
In my app.controller.js I have added three event listeners and attached a deleteStudent method.

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', this.deleteStudent, false);
    window.addEventListener(
      'unload',
      () => {
        this.deleteStudent
      },
      false
    );
    window.addEventListener('pagehide', this.deleteStudent, false);

deleteStudent() {
 let Url = "http://localhost:9000/students/3";
    const deleteMethod = {
      method: 'DELETE',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      keepalive: true
    };
    fetch(Url, deleteMethod);
}
```

The API call is not reaching backend but getting listed on the chrome network tab as **pending** state.

*The above used delete API is created in Node js and working fine with postman.

I have to call this API at the time of page unload only, where it is recommended to use either fetch API with **keep-alive** property **true** or use sendBeacon(), but my backend API is of type **DELETE** therefore I can not use sendBeacon() as it only supports POST.

Comment: Hi there. You didn't provide much information in your question regarding your problem. You got to locate the issue first - is the issue that the event listener callback is not called? You can verify with a breakpoint, and please note those events are not fired reliably https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/pagehide_event#usage_notes. Or is the issue that callback is called but the request somehow fails? Again, keeping the logs between page navigations or setting a breakpoint might help.

Comment: Hi @DanMacák, event listener callback is called and if I check on the network tab after pausing at the breakpoint after fetch then I can see the API call is triggered with **pending** state but it is not reaching to the backend API.

Comment: I tried your code example and for me it works just fine in Chrome. Yes, I also get the **pending** state, but when I check my proxy (Fiddler), I see the server returns a 200 response for a DELETE request https://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/delete/719/. So are you really sure that the request doesn't hit your server? If not, does it work with the dummy endpoint above?

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue. Fetch API with keepalive worked well on Chrome, but it was very unreliable on Firefox. The request did not reach the server most of the time.

As a hack, I had to use the following code after calling the Fetch API to delay window close/refresh by 0.5 seconds:

```
beforeUnloadHandler() {
    fetch(`http://localhost:8080/api', {
    keepalive: true,
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(payload),
  });
    const time = Date.now();
    while ((Date.now() - time) < 500) {

    }
    return true;
  }
```

And yes, I do realize that this code is ugly. But desperate times!!!

Comment: "but it was very unreliable on Firefox....." Yes, I agree that Firefox has to support it reliably on all scenarios page reload/close tab/browser shutdown including Firefox mobile browsers. In addition, your **hack to delay 0.5 seconds** to save the crucial data before close is nice & appreciate it!

Comment: Firefox and Safari still sucks at fetch API behavior on beforeUnload event. They should provide consistent support. Chrome & Edge looks better & promising.